# Using multiple colors inside one equation using alert and other commands

Tags: equations, color

If I do the following, then both A and B turn out red.

```
\alert{A} + \alert{B}
```

Can I make only B into blue?

If there a separate existing command?

Or, is it possible to make another command `alertblue` and write

```
\alert{A} + \alertblue{B}
```

?

Comment: Does inserting `\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=blue}` before ` \alert{B}` give you what you want?

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand. Here, "alerted text" is just `B`. You mean I have to type B twice so that `\setbeamercolor{B}{fg=blue}\alert{B}` ?

Comment: What I meant is `\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Change alert color}
\alert{A} + \setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=blue}\alert{B}
\end{frame}
\end{document}`.

Comment: Or `\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand{\alertblue}[1]{\begingroup%
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=blue}\alert{#1}\endgroup}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Change alert color}
$\alert{A} + \alertblue{B}=\alert{C}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the alert color with `\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=<color>}`. You can define an `\alertblue` command as follows.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand<>{\alertblue}[1]{\begingroup%
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=blue}\alert{#1}\endgroup}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Change alert color}
$\alert<1>{A}\pause + \alertblue<2>{B}\pause=\alert<3>{C}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here, `<>` in `\newcommand<>...` makes sure that the command understands overlay specifications, and `\begingroup...\endgroup` ensures that the color change is only local, i.e. the next ordinary `\alert` will use the default color again.

An arguably more versatile version thereof is

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand<>{\ColorAlert}[2][blue]{\begingroup%
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=#1}\alert{#2}\endgroup}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Change alert color}
$y$ stays blue
\[x+\ColorAlert{y}=z\]
I learned the \texttt{.(1)} trick from samcarter. 
\[\alert<.(1)>{A}\pause +
\ColorAlert<.(1)>{B}\pause=\ColorAlert[orange]<.(1)>{C}\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand<>{\ColorAlert}[2][blue]{\begingroup%
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=#1}\alert#3{#2}\endgroup}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Change alert color}
$y$ stays blue
\[x+\ColorAlert{y}=z\]
I learned the \texttt{.(1)} trick from samcarter. 
\[\alert<.(1)>{A}\pause +
\ColorAlert<.(1)>{B}\pause=\ColorAlert[orange]<.(1)>{C}\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A shorter option is the following code:

```
{\color{blue}TEXT YOU WANT IN BLUE}
```